# unable to run selenium test cases on docker container

Tags: java, docker, selenium-grid

I have set up a Selenium grid and selenium chrome node as docker continers and also created an container for my test suite.
But once i try to run the test cases it is failing providing the below error message

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:42:16'
System info: host: '267891a44849', ip: '172.17.0.3', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '11.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:4444
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

created an docker image for my automation code through docker file

created an docker network

created an hub on docker using selenium grid

linked node to this hub

and tried to run the code

My Dockerfile to create image for automation code

```
FROM node AS chrome
USER root
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN apt-get install unzip && \
    wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/77.0.3865.40/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /home/app/chromedriver

FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-11-slim
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
COPY Dockerfile /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
COPY --from=chrome /home/app/chromedriver /home/app
RUN chmod u+x chromedriver
ENTRYPOINT mvn clean test
```

Also I can see docker hub and node up for selenium

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
e95780aac878        selenium/node-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   29 hours ago        Up 29 hours                                  selenium-node
7e23e59006fb        selenium/hub           "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   29 hours ago        Up 29 hours         0.0.0.0:4446->4444/tcp   selenium-hub
```

And my SetUp.java contians code as below

```
String nodeURL= "http://localhost:4446/wd/hub";
ChromeOptions remoteOptions = new ChromeOptions();
driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeURL), remoteOptions);
```

but on executing

```
$ docker run --rm -e SELENIUM_HUB=selenium-node --network grid <my automaiotn code image>
```

I am getting below error

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running Parallel01IT
inside after

Failed scenarios:
/home/app/src/test/java/features/NonRes.feature:49 

1 Scenarios (1 failed)
3 Steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
2m0.810s

org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: '61da76b392d3', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:566)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:145)


org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: 
Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: '61da76b392d3', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.184-linuxkit', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

**But When I run the same test cases from my local [my laptop] on those docker selenium grid containers it is working fine**
However running the same test case as a docker container is failing.

Comment: Couple of pointers- should not have two `FROM` statements in a single Dockerfile, second - do not try to run as Root. It is suggested to not run as root.

Comment: Can you try changing `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`(there are several `localhost` when you run docker images and it is easy to get confused) and recheck ports (for some reason port 4446 is linked to port 4444 of image `selenium/hub`)

Answer (score 0):

Run the `chromedriver` with a `headless` option. I have faced the same problem before and this resolved it.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
```